# Does parApply() divide the matrix and then process each?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, apply, rparallel

Suppose I have a `parApply()` call as follows:

```
cl <- makeCluster("FORK", 5)
parApply(cl = cl, X = my.mat, MARGIN = 1, FUN = myFun)
```

Where `nrow(my.mat)` is very big but `myFun()` is computed very fast. Note that the number of cores of `cl` is `5`. I wonder how parallelization is carried out.

> Is `my.mat` divided into 5 submatrices, then each processed by a thread, then combined together after all threads are done? Or is it done by sending elements of `my.mat` to each thread one by one?

Comment: As specified by `MARGIN = 1` the process is done by lines. http://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~jerrick/courses/stat701/notes/parallel.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some explanation from the R documentation:

> **parLapply**, **parSapply**, and **parApply** are parallel versions of lapply,
> sapply and apply. *Chunks of computation are statically allocated to
> nodes using* **clusterApply**. By default, the number of chunks is the same
> as the number of nodes. **parLapplyLB**, **parSapplyLB** are load-balancing
> versions, intended for use when applying FUN to different elements of
> X takes quite variable amounts of time, and either the function is
> deterministic or reproducible results are not required. Chunks of
> computation are allocated dynamically to nodes using **clusterApplyLB**.

Note that there are some changes done in R/3.5.0:

> From R 3.5.0, the default number of chunks is twice the number of
> nodes. Before R 3.5.0, the (fixed) number of chunks was the same as
> the number of nodes. As for **clusterApplyLB**, with load balancing the
> node that executes a particular job is non-deterministic and
> simulations that assign RNG streams to nodes will not be reproducible.
>
> **clusterApply** calls fun on the first node with arguments x[[1]] and
> ..., on the second node with x[[2]] and ..., and so on, recycling
> nodes as needed.

There is `clusterApplyLB` that works slightly differently:

> **clusterApplyLB** is a load balancing version of clusterApply. If the
> length n of x is not greater than the number of nodes p, then a job is
> sent to n nodes. Otherwise the first p jobs are placed in order on the
> p nodes. When the first job completes, the next job is placed on the
> node that has become free; this continues until all jobs are complete.
> Using **clusterApplyLB** can result in better cluster utilization than
> using **clusterApply**, but increased communication can reduce
> performance. Furthermore, the node that executes a particular job is
> non-deterministic. This means that simulations that assign RNG streams
> to nodes will not be reproducible.

So when you are using `parApply` your matrix is divided into 5 chunks. Each chunk is processed by one of the cores. In case of par*ApplyLB family of functions the elements are assigned to the cores one by one and once a core is finished with its task, another one is assigned to it.

Here is an output from the following code:

```r
library(parallel)

my.mat <- matrix(c(1:20,rep(0,20)), ncol=2)
head(my.mat)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    0
# [2,]    2    0
# [3,]    3    0
# [4,]    4    0
# [5,]    5    0
# [6,]    6    0

cl <- makeCluster(5, "FORK")
parApply(cl = cl, X = my.mat, MARGIN = 1, FUN = \(x) sprintf("sum= %d   pid=%d", sum(x), Sys.getpid()))
# [1] "sum=1   pid=42569" 
# [2] "sum=2   pid=42569" 
# [3] "sum=3   pid=42569" 
# [4] "sum=4   pid=42569" 
# [5] "sum=5   pid=42570" 
# [6] "sum=6   pid=42570" 
# [7] "sum=7   pid=42570" 
# [8] "sum=8   pid=42570" 
# [9] "sum=9   pid=42571" 
# [10] "sum=10   pid=42571"
# [11] "sum=11   pid=42571"
# [12] "sum=12   pid=42571"
# [13] "sum=13   pid=42572"
# [14] "sum=14   pid=42572"
# [15] "sum=15   pid=42572"
# [16] "sum=16   pid=42572"
# [17] "sum=17   pid=42573"
# [18] "sum=18   pid=42573"
# [19] "sum=19   pid=42573"
# [20] "sum=20   pid=42573"


stopCluster(cl)
```

Note the difference with the following output (see how pid values are distributed) if I use `parLapplyLB` with chunk size=1:

```r
mylist <- 1:20
cl <- makeCluster(5, "FORK")
parLapplyLB(cl = cl, X = mylist,\(x) sprintf("sum=%d   pid=%d", sum(x), Sys.getpid()), chunk.size = 1)
# [[1]]
# [1] "sum=1   pid=64019"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "sum=2   pid=64020"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "sum=3   pid=64021"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "sum=4   pid=64022"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "sum=5   pid=64023"
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] "sum=6   pid=64019"
# 
# [[7]]
# [1] "sum=7   pid=64020"
# 
# [[8]]
# [1] "sum=8   pid=64019"
# 
# [[9]]
# [1] "sum=9   pid=64020"
# 
# [[10]]
# [1] "sum=10   pid=64019"
# . . .
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Using `Sys.getpid()` is a great tip for constructing examples inspecting things like this!